# cryptsetup - No key available with this passphrase when reading disk

Tags: luks

I have my old system (x86 one where I have created encrypted partition).

Now on same machine when I boot on different system (different kernel version and amd64 arch) I cannot open my encrypted disk.

When I try to open it i got this:

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc2 segate_160
No key available with this passphrase.
```

I can read header:

```
# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdc2
LUKS header information for /dev/sdc2

Version:        1
Cipher name:    blowfish
Cipher mode:    cbc-plain
Hash spec:      whirlpool
```

I'm sure that password is correct (I copy-paste it).

The blowfish modules are loaded

```
# lsmod |grep blowfish
blowfish_x86_64        24576  0
blowfish_generic       16384  0
blowfish_common        20480  2 blowfish_generic,blowfish_x86_64
```

What else can be wrong? why I cannot decrypt this disk?

Comment: If you run the luksDump command on the two systems, do you see the same key slot(s) in ENABLED state, with the same info (salt, etc)?

Comment: Yes, output on both system are exactly the same.